# Enter an array of objects into an Arraylist of objects and change attribute

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

i hope someone can help me, i'm struggling with this since yesterday...

I'm working right now on a Hotel Management System project.
What i'm trying to do is, to put an array[] Clients into an ArrayList of Rooms and then set this room attribute to 'occupied = true' and save that so if i try to use that room for other client it doesn't let me.

Room class

```
public class Room {
    private int number;
    private float price= 30.5f;
    private boolean occupied = false;
    private Client[] hosts;

    public Room(int number, Client[] hosts) {
        this.number= number;
        this.hosts= hosts;
    }

    public void setOccupied() {
        this.occupied = true;
    }
}
```

Client class

```
public class Client {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public Client(String id, String name, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name= name;
        this.lastName= lastName;
    }
}
```

This is what i've got on my Main so far... i'm calling the next function

```
public void checkIn(ArrayList<Room> myRooms){
        int roomNumber;
        String id;
        String name;
        String lastName;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int people = input.nextInt();
        Client[] array = new Client[people];


        for (int i = 0; i < people; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter ID" + (i+1));
            id = input.next();

            System.out.println("Enter name " + (i+1));
            name= input.next();

            System.out.println("Enter last name " + (i+1));
            lastName= input.next();

            array[i] = new Client(id,name,lastName);

        }

        System.out.print("Assign to room number... : ");
        roomNumber = input.nextInt();

        myRooms.add(new Room(roomNumber, array));

        //here i tried doing:
        //room.set().setOccupied();
        //room.set(roomNumber).setOccupied();

        //but .set() expects an index...

    }
```

Once i have this, i want to create a function that shows a list of rooms that are occupied

Excuse my english since i'm Spanish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways to tackle this, probably what i would do is overload my room constructor so that you can set if it's occupied or not once you instantiate it like:

```
public Room(int number, Client[] hosts, boolean occupied)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.hosts = hosts;
        this.occupied = true;
    }
```

and in your `checkIn()` method just add true when instantiating your room inside the list:

```
myRooms.add(new Room(roomNumber, array, true));
```

Comment: But if I instantiate the room already occupied how do I make it false when checkout?

Comment: You can add a setter to the room class just like your `setOccupied()` method

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't creating a reference-able instance of Room when you call
`myRooms.add(new Room(roomNumber, array));`
you can't then say 
`room.setOccupied();`
You can fix this two ways: First, as Bahij.Mik said, you could call `this.occupied = true;` in the Room constructor. Or, you could simply create a new instance of a Room in your checkIn method. This would look like:

```
    Room newRoom = new Room(roomNumber, array);
    newRoom.setOccupied();
```

whenever someone checks in.

As for creating a function to check which rooms are occupied, make an array of room numbers and then try:

```
    public String[][] findOccupiedRooms(int[] roomNumbers) {
        String[][] roomList = new String[roomNumbers.length][1];
        for(int i = 0; i < roomNumbers.length; i++) {
           if(roomNumbers[i].isOccupied() == true) {
                 roomList[i][0] = "" + roomNumbers[i];
                 roomList[i][1] = "occupied";
           } else {
                 roomList[i][0] = "" + roomNumbers[i];
                 roomList[i][1] = "vacant";
           }
        }
        return roomList[][];
     }
```

This returns a 2-dimensional array that stores the room number and whether it is occupied or vacant. Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I hope it helps.